# Restrict Account Owner to Contact Owner based on custom checkbox

Tags: apex

I need to restrict account owner  to contact owner sync based on a check box. If the check box is checked, it should not update the Contact owner.

Whether the check box is checked or unchecked it's changing the contact owner.

Please advise where I need to make the change in the code to make it work.

Below is the apex code:

```
trigger Contactownerupdatetrigger on Account (after update)
{
    List<Contact> lstContactToBeUpdated = new List<Contact>();
    Map<Id, Id> mapAccountId_OwnerId = new Map<Id, Id>();

    for (Account a : Trigger.new){
        if (a.DNC_Owner__c==true){
            if (a.OwnerId == Trigger.newMap.get(a.Id).OwnerId){
                mapAccountId_OwnerId.put(a.Id, a.OwnerId);
            }
        }
    }

    for(Contact objContact : [Select Id, OwnerId, AccountId from Contact where AccountId IN: mapAccountId_OwnerId.keySet()]) {
        objContact.OwnerId = mapAccountId_OwnerId.get(objContact.AccountId);
        lstContactToBeUpdated.add(objContact);
    }

    If(!lstContactToBeUpdated.isEmpty())
        Update lstContactToBeUpdated;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your code here exact as it is in your org? Few points:

```
if (a.DNC_Owner__c==true){
    if (a.OwnerId == Trigger.newMap.get(a.Id).OwnerId){
        mapAccountId_OwnerId.put(a.Id, a.OwnerId);
```

1. You're making the update if `DNC_Owner__c` is `true` which seems to
   be the opposite of what you say you want.
2. You're looping over `trigger.new` and comparing with values in
   `trigger.newMap`, so they're always going to match. One of these
   should be using the old data.

Right now this would update the contact owner if the checkbox is checked, but not otherwise. Unless I'm being dim I can't see how this would update the contact owner if that checkbox was unchecked.